# ASP Classic+SQL server 2000

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2000

```
UPDATE a 
SET a.status =  1 
FROM tbl_Assets2010 AS a 
INNER JOIN tbl_Master AS m ON a.AssetNo = m.AssetNo 
WHERE a.AssetNo =" & Request.Form(AssetNo")
```

Error

> Syntax error converting the varchar value '1006-101' to a column of
>   data type int.

I get value from text field.what is correct code I must use ya.

Comment: Can you specify what is your table structure? Like column names with their data types? And also mention the values that you are sending it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle it as a string (notice the apostrophes around your Request.Form below).

```
UPDATE a SET a.status = 1 FROM tbl_Assets2010 AS a INNER JOIN tbl_Master AS m ON a.AssetNo = m.AssetNo WHERE a.AssetNo ='" & Request.Form(AssetNo") & "'"
```

Comment: @user988651: That'll work but I wouldn't use it.  You expose your site to SQL Injection attacks.  Always use parameterised queries.

Comment: Yes, this solution requires to sanitize the input before adding it to the SQL query.